# Does my JUnit test changes the database?

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, junit

I have been writing unit tests for my program. I wrote a test which inserts data into a database and then checks if this data actually was added. So now I am wondering if this test actually added the data permanently to the database (I can't access it because it's not mine so I can't check). If someone could give me an answer, that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you commit the changes you store it permanently in the database.

Comment: If your test involves the database then it isn't a unit test, it's an _integration_ test.

Comment: If the test checks for the data being added, there are two options. a) The test is successful and the data is added to the database or b) The test fails and data isn't added to the database.

Comment: First of all, if your java application can work with database through JDBC driver then you have an configuration to connect to remote DB. At least, readonly access. Second, you should attache code sample and JDBC configuration so that we can answer correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If you don't want to change anything to the database, use a mock database you set up locally, or remove the inserted data after you add and check it.
Actually. you should ALWAYS remove the data you added, since otherwise the unit test will be rendered useless after the first execution as the data will not be added anymore since it's already there and the assertion will always succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test really shouldn't insert data into a database. You should use a database mocking framework instead.

Integration tests on the other hand test multi-tier interaction like this.

This matters because generally unit tests are executed at build time whereas integration tests are executed either ad-hoc, before checking-in to version control, or during continuous integration builds.

Never-the-less, to answer your question, you should be doing your inserts in a transaction or session that you can rollback.

Alternatively, you could also override your datasource connection parameters in your application context to point to a temporary local [in-memory database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases) like H2.

Another, less preferable option would be to have the data cleaned up after the test, test-case, or test-suite is finished.

Here are some JUnit mocking libraries that can help you test database transactions:

- [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/)
- [MockRunner](http://mockrunner.sourceforge.net/)
- [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)